# Simulate Automotive Speedometer Sender

Tags: arduino, grounding, automotive, gauge

I am working on a project and I have run into a little bit of a problem.  I have a speedometer gauge that I am trying to send a signal to on a bench (out of car).

The way in wich the it works is pictured as follows.
[image]

One side is ground and the other side goes to the gauge as the sender.

So essentially what I need to do is create a circuit that simulates grounding the sender pin to ground at a high frequency with a square wave and 50% duty cycle.

I thought about using some sort of relay and turning it on and off really fast but that probably wont be fast enough and will probably wear out the relay really fast.

I would like to be able to use an Arduino to accomplish this.

Comment: use a sender and an electric drill

Comment: Do you know what the amplitude and frequency (or max frequency) your pulse train needs to be?  Arduino has, I believe, a pulse-width modulation (PWM) function, but it may not be sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisM. need to be able to change the frequency and from what I was understanding when you adjust the PWM you are actually changing the duty cycle, not the frequency.  Either way, I have tried this with unsuccessful results.

Comment: Which shaft is the sender disc connected to on the car? Then the tyre circumference, final drive ratio and possiblya gear ratio will give you the number of pulses per km or 100m and you should already know the number of teeth...

Comment: @SolarMike I am not really worried about that at the moment, I am just trying to replicate the signal

Comment: But that will tell you the max frequency needed

Answer (score 0):

A pot-controlled clock can be made with an RC CMOS  Schmitt Inverter Relaxation Osc , which are very common. e.g. You choose RC for the lowest RPM then reduce pot R to 1/10th R for 10x RPM.

Without voltage specs, you need to measure and get close to this.

Comment: I could be wrong but it seems to be looking for a short to ground, no voltage, I tried to feed it with a wave generator at 5v and got nothing to work.  Attached is the full schematic and you can see one side of the sender is ground the other is to the gauge itself.  The gauge does receive 12v however.

http://www.e30zone.net/e30zonewiki/images/b/b2/Instrument_Cluster.pdf

Comment: OK, so an NPN switch should work on clock output

Comment: Is that essentially what is going on in this video?

There's a schematic at 4:03
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBKfB2GNPbU

Comment: Yes except they used a power NPN darlington switch. Which is good.

Comment: As opposed to a MOSFET, which would be easier to control saw with a PWM pin like that?